# How can i remove the ? (symbol) from url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, symbols

I have done blog part in simple php without using blog concept of wordpress.I have done that work but problem is ?(Symbol) is displaying in url.Is there any way to remove ?(Symbol)from url for seo friendly.

Comment: The question mark is not a SEO problem in itself. Can you clarify what the issue is, maybe show an example URL and how you want to change it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`/%post_ID%/%postname%` will show your URL as `domain.com/1/hello-world`

**You can get more help at** http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the backend, just go to Settings > Permalinks and set it to the one titled 'post name'

This will give you a much more SEO friendly url throughout your blog, and no need for any .htaccess nonsense!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it from the backend of wordpress.

Go to admin side.
Settings -> Permalinks
Then select the post name option there.

Then the url will become seo friendly.